# How to keep some information secure and use it from behind private procedure

Tags: c#

This code is work  how can I keep user name and password secure and can use from many code so when i change password then i can change one page and effect to many code

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ExportXMLData
{
  class ExportXML
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      ExportXML exportXML = new ExportXML();
      exportXML.Run();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
      // Change the variables to reflect values needed for
      // your computer and database properties.
      string Database = "";
      string Server = "localhost";
      string User = "";
      string Pass = "";
      string TableName = "";
      string XMLRootNodeName = "Root";
      string OutputFileName = "output.xml";

      string conn = 
    "Database=" + Database + ";" + 
    "Server=" + Server + ";" +
    "Uid=" + User + ";" +
    "Pwd=" + Pass;

      MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(conn);
      MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
      adapter.TableMappings.Add("Table", TableName);
      connection.Open();
      MySqlCommand query = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM "
                        + TableName, connection);
      query.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
      adapter.SelectCommand = query;
      DataSet ds = new DataSet(XMLRootNodeName);
      adapter.Fill(ds);
      connection.Close();

      ds.WriteXml(OutputFileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Never create sql query with string concatenation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just make the 'User' and 'Pass' variables into properties on the 'ExportXML' class.

Answer (score 0):

It's depending to architecture. Where you want to have this access. You can declare `private string Pass` in your class and use for example [Friend assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to access an internal member of a public classes.